# Asterisk behind firewall (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, asterisk, firewall

Asterisk 16.9 on AWS EC2
BTW clients are behind firewall too. but in
pjsip.conf

```
[XXX]
    type = endpoint
    ...
    direct-media = no
    rtp_symmetric = yes
    ....
```

Signalling works good.

but client shows source of incomming call XXX@172.31.x.x - local network of AWS VPC. No sound.

Shoud I add iptables rules to nat table or only add something to pjsip.conf?

Answer (score 1):

AWS EC2 do NAT.

So you have setup asterisk to work like NATed box.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-sip-nat/

i.e inform about external ip, localnet etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

`[transport-udp]
    type = transport
    ....
    local_net = 127.0.0.1/32
    local_net = LOCAL_NET_IP
    external_media_address = WAN_IP`

to traverse firewall